# Why can't I have an auto_ptr in an Exception class

Tags: c++, exception, auto-ptr

I have a problem with auto_ptr in Exception classes, that I eventually reduced to:

```
#include <memory>

class MyException
{
    std::auto_ptr<int> m_foo2;
};

int main()
{
    try
    {
        throw MyException();
    }
    catch (const MyException&)
    {

    }
    return 0;
}
```

This fails to compile with:

> /perforce/unstable/test/Common/Exceptions/TestException4.cpp: In
>   function 'int main()':
>   /perforce/unstable/test/Common/Exceptions/TestException4.cpp:12:
>   error: no matching function for call to
>   'MyException::MyException(MyException)'
>   /perforce/unstable/test/Common/Exceptions/TestException4.cpp:4: note:
>   candidates are: MyException::MyException()
>   /perforce/unstable/test/Common/Exceptions/TestException4.cpp:4: note: 
>   MyException::MyException(MyException&)
>   /perforce/unstable/test/Common/Exceptions/TestException4.cpp:12:
>   error:   in thrown expression

And the error goes away if I remove the auto_ptr.

Is this because the exception is being copied or assigned? Is there a way of using `auto_ptr`s in an Exception?

Comment: Wow, high quality answers here. Must be a good question. :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Is this because the exception is being copied or assigned?

Indeed it is. The standard specifies how an exception is thrown in C++11 15.1/3:

> A throw-expression initializes a temporary object, [...].
>   The temporary is an lvalue and is used to initialize the variable named in the matching handler.

The initialisation is done with the implicit copy constructor. This is declared as `MyException(MyException&)`, since there is a member that requires a non-`const` reference argument (as specified in C++11 12.8/9). The temporary object can't be bound to a non-`const` reference, and so the construction fails.

> Is there a way of using auto_ptrs in an Exception?

If you're able to use C++11, then you could use `unique_ptr` instead, and consign `auto_ptr` to the bowels of history. Your class would have an implicit move constructor, declared as `MyException(MyException&&)`, which could be used to initialise it from a temporary.

Otherwise, you could throw a non-temporary value:

```
MyException ex;
throw ex;
```

or you could hack your class to allow initialisation from a `const` reference by adding an explicit copy constructor and using `const_cast` or `mutable` to allow that to copy the `auto_ptr` - but that is potentially dangerous, and I wouldn't recommend it.